# How to use a parameters value as the property to be selected in a LINQ Query?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am using LINQ-to-Entities and here is my query

```
public void SomeFunction(string searchField)
{
var data = from a in dx.SomeTable where         
                a.SomeProperty="270"
                select a;
.
.
.

}
```

Now if I had to use the value of the parameter "searchField" as the property to be selected in the where clause then how do I do it ?

i.e I want to assign the value of the parameter "searchField" to the property I am checking in the where clause.

So ... the value of "SomeProperty" in a.SomeProperty must be the value of "searchField". How to do this ?

PS :

I dont want a.SomeProperty=searchField.

What I want is "SomeProperty" itself to be replaced by the value of "searchField" and then , this has to be checked to see if its equal to 270.

Comment: In the code that calls `SomeFunction`, do you know the type of `a`, or do you just know that it is an object with a property called `SomeProperty` ?

Comment: Hi,
The function deals with only one particular table called "SomeTable" which I can access using the datacontext "dx"

I know that there are many properties(columns in effect) for that table and that the "someField" value will be the name of one of those columns. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scottgu posted how to do this a while ago:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**If the caller knows the type of your `a`** (let's say it's `MyType`), I would suggest that you don't need dynamic LINQ - you can just pass in a predicate function:

```
public void SomeFunction(Func<MyType, bool> selector)
{
    // ...
    var data =  from a in dx.SomeTable
                where selector(a)
                select a;
}

// Calling code
SomeFunction(a => a.SomeProperty == "270");
```

Or if you want to keep the `270` value within `SomeFunction`, pass in a projection function to pull out `SomeProperty` :

```
public void SomeFunction(Func<MyType, string> propertyExtractor)
{
    // ...
    var data = from a in dx.SomeTable
               where propertyExtractor(a) == "270"
               select a;
}

// Calling code
SomeFunction(a => a.SomeProperty);
```

(apologies if this doesn't compile, am currently away from a compiler)

Comment: Thanks Aakash I will try to check that out :)